# Android Webview "XMLHttpRequest cannot load <xmlurl>.wildcard '*' cannot be used'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when credentials flag is true"

Tags: javascript, android, webview, cors

But nothing is showing on webview. I have checked that the html i am trying to load is working perfectly on browser.

Everything works fine accept at one state I encounter the XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... Origin  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.example.gowsample;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
         private WebView mWebview ;

         @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    mWebview  = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    mWebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                    mWebview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                    mWebview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
                    mWebview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                    mWebview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());         

    String myvar = ""; 

    String summary = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"><!-- Video.js 4 -->\n<link href=\"http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n<script src=\"http://mysite/video.js\"></script>\n<!-- Common -->\n<link href=\"http://mysite/bin/videojs.vast.vpaid.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n<!-- Video.js 5 -->\n<script src=\"http://mysite/bin/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.min.js\"></script>\n<script src=\"http://mysite/VPAID1/bin/es5-shim.js\"></script>\n<script src=\"http://mysite/VPAID1/bin/ie8fix.js\"></script>\n<video id=\"example_video_1\" class=\"video-js vjs-default-skin\"\n    controls preload=\"auto\" width=\"300\" height=\"250\"\n    poster=\"http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png\"\n    data-setup='{\n      \"plugins\": {\n      \"vastClient\": {\n        \"adTagUrl\": \"http://mysite/VPAID1/sincity.xml\",\n        \"adCancelTimeout\": 5000,\n        \"adsEnabled\": true\n        }\n      }\n    }'>\n  <source src=\"http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4\" type='video/mp4'/>\n\n \n</video>\n</html>";
    String html =summary; 
    mWebview.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");

            }

    }
```

the console says that:

> 08-03 11:38:17.961: I/chromium(2858): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)]
>   "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://mysite/VPAID1/sincity.xml. A wildcard
>   '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when
>   the credentials flag is true. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed
>   access.",

```
 source: data:text/html; charset=utf-8,<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><!-- Video.js 4 --><link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="http://104.145.233.9/~proddemo/Vrtcal/VPAID1/video.js"></script><!-- Common --><link href="http://mysite/bin/videojs.vast.vpaid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- Video.js 5 --><script src="http://mysite/bin/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.min.js"></script><script src="http://mysite/VPAID1/bin/es5-shim.js"></script><script src="http://mysite/VPAID1/bin/ie8fix.js"></script><video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"    controls preload="auto" width="300" height="250"    poster="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png"    data-setup='{      "plugins": {      "vastClient": {        "adTagUrl": "http:/mysite/VPAID1/sincity.xml",        "adCancelTimeout": 5000,        "adsEnabled": true        }      }    }'>  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'/> </video></html> (0)
```

how to solve this error..